# MYSQL most common column value and AVG in one query

Tags: mysql, count, average

I have one table with columns that contains data about wind (wind,gusts, and direction)

I want to get average for wind and gust and most common value for direction for selected time period

I can manage to do it in two queries but don't know how to merge them

```
SELECT
    avg(wind) as wind,
    avg(gust) as gust
FROM
    station
WHERE
    id >='2018-10-20 00:00:00' AND id <'2018-10-20 04:00:00'

SELECT
    direction,
    count(direction) as sm
FROM
    station
WHERE
    id >='2018-10-20 00:00:00' AND id <'2018-10-20 04:00:00'
GROUP BY
    direction
ORDER BY
    sm DESC LIMIT 1
```

i tried

```
SELECT
    avg(wind) as wind,
    avg(gust) as gust,
    direction,
    count(direction) as sm
FROM
    station
WHERE
    id >='2018-10-20 00:00:00' AND id <'2018-10-20 04:00:00'
GROUP BY
    direction
ORDER BY
    sm DESC LIMIT 1
```

but this will calculate average for data but only where direction is most common value. Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT direction,
       t1.wind,
       t1.gust,
       count(direction) as sm
FROM station CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT avg(wind) as wind,
           avg(gust) as gust 
    FROM station 
    WHERE id >='2018-10-20 00:00:00' AND id <'2018-10-20 04:00:00' 
) t1
WHERE id >='2018-10-20 00:00:00' AND id <'2018-10-20 04:00:00' 
GROUP BY direction 
ORDER BY sm DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

or you can use subquery in `select`

```
SELECT direction,
       (select avg(wind) FROM station) wind,
       (select avg(gust) FROM station) gust,
       count(direction) as sm
FROM station 
WHERE id >='2018-10-20 00:00:00' AND id <'2018-10-20 04:00:00' 
GROUP BY direction 
ORDER BY sm DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Great. Thx. The first one did the job. The second one however did not return accurate results.

Comment: @Jakadinho No problem glad to help :)